# How to use setResult() with an AlertDialog class?

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to create a separated class to show an AlertDialog.
The problem is that if I create a class extending an Activity and creating a Dialog in the activity I get a black background instead of a transparent one. I have used:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

In my Manifest and the title and background is removed but I don't get the same appearance as when you create a Dialog. Here is my code:

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Creo el dialogo
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.AnalyzerDialogSaveTitle));
        alert.setMessage(getString(R.string.AnalyzerDialogFileName));

        // Creamos un EditView para que el usuario escriba
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        alert.setView(input);
        alert.show();

    }

}
```

I also tried to extends AlertDialog and Dialog instead of Activity but I can't use setResult() to invoke onActivityResult() when I press a button and I simply can't call it using startActivityForResult().

How can I get a real Dialog (not themed because it doesn't look as when you use AlertDialog class) and use startActivityForResult to call it?

Thank you :)

**----- EDIT -----**

I have also tried Theme.Dialog but it is the same as I don't get the same appearance. Here is what I mean:

**Android AlertDialog**

[image: Android AlertDialog]

**Theme.Dialog or Theme.Traslucent.NoTitleBar**

[image: Theme.Dialog or Theme.Traslucent.NoTitleBar]

As you can see the appearance you get is no the same.

Answer (score 0):

To show the activity as Dialog use android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dilalog" instead of Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.